# Is Principal Wood inspired by Blade?

Tags: marvel, buffy-the-vampire-slayer, character-similarity

In *Buffy* we meet school principal [Robin Wood](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Wood_(Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer)) who ends up fighting vampires. I started wondering if he was influenced by the Marvel comic book character [Blade](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_(comics)). Blade also fights vampires, and the two vaguely resemble one another in outward physical appearance and build.

It certainly wouldn't be the first (or even the hundredth) reference to popular comic book characters in *Buffy*. **Have those involved with making the show commented as to whether Wood was based on Blade?**

[image]

Comment: I presume you mean "was Whedon's development of the character of Robin Wood influenced by Blade?" rather than "Does Robin Wood read Blade comics".

Comment: @Richard lol, yes, the first one, that's what I meant. :)

Comment: Might be worth editing the question to make that distinction a bit clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, absolutely he was. Whedon cites "Blade the Vampire Slayer" (and specifically [The Tomb of the Dracula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tomb_of_Dracula)) as one of the [key influences](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IPNSR9PQ76gC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=%22much%20of%20the%20original%20blade%22%20and%20whedon&source=bl&ots=J0E0vi5mCe&sig=nrU2fKBYAgmt85T4WkSzQimxjug&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22much%20of%20the%20original%20blade%22%20and%20whedon&f=false) in [the development](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=n_sOkSb8fYgC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=%22Robin%20Wood%22%20and%20interview%20and%20%22blade%22&source=bl&ots=ZFc7PW24B5&sig=hjmU--G_ACpcdD1r4DFusR430jU&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Robin%20Wood%22%20and%20interview%20and%20%22blade%22&f=false) of the characters of Robin and Nikki Wood. He and Doug Petric are on record as being chuffed to bits that they actually got Gene Colan (the co-creator of Blade) to pencil a later Buffy comic in '[Tales of the Slayers #7](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Nikki_Goes_Down!)':

> **Westfield:** *Can you say anything more about the Tales of the Slayers book?*
>
> **Whedon:** *We don't have a date for it, **but we talked about this when we were shooting the seventies flashback of Spike killing a
>   slayer on a subway. I said to Doug Petric, who's one of my writers and
>   who's written some of the Buffy comics and is, like me, a comic book
>   nut, "God. We should do a compendium of stories of slayers throughout
>   history." And he was like "I get to do the seventies slayer on the
>   subway." He's actually doing it with Gene Colan. There was so much of
>   the original Blade and Tomb of Dracula in that whole sequence.** We were
>   so into that. We pitched that to Scott and he was all over it and it
>   turned out that practically my entire staff wanted to do it. They all
>   picked an era and we talked about length and I'm doing three little
>   pieces in it myself. It's a different artist for every piece and we're
>   getting some really exciting people to*

Interestingly, Robin Wood's character seems to have been heavily shaped by (and possibly named for) the archetypal "haunted warrior" described in the seminal 1979 essay "[An Introduction to the American Horror Film](https://books.google.gr/books?hl=el&output=html_text&id=QHg7m_ESR54C&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=the%20true%20subject%20of%20the%20horror%20genre%20is%20the%20struggle%20for%20recognition%20of%20all%20that%20our%20civilization%20represses%20or%20oppresses)" written by film critic Robin Wood, something that remains essential reading for all students of film and was almost certainly the reference point for Whedon's development of Buffy and the later "Cabin in the Woods".